# How do I use an access token in modules?

Tags: python, global-variables

I have an api access token that is used in several of my Python modules. I could declare it as a Global variable but I'm reading that global variables aren't a good idea. How is this normally done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a config module and import it from there.

config.py:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'some_value'
SOME_OTHER_THING = 42
```

app.py:

```
from config import ACCESS_TOKEN

some_api.do_request(token=ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

The advantage of this method is that you can, at some future time, change the way the constant is 'calculated'. For example:

config.py:

```
if ENVIRONMENT == 'production':
  from production_config import ACCESS_TOKEN
else:
  from development_config import ACCESS_TOKEN
```